# Unable to install IPOPT for python (missing library dependency)

Tags: python, installation, ipopt

I built IPOPT from source at `/usr/local/` 
Then I tried to install ipopt for **python** `python setup.py install`

However the installer **complained** (error) that it could not locate `IpStdCInterface.h`
I then modified the content of setup.py file as follows: (line 1 and 3 had wrong paths)

```
    IPOPT_ICLUDE_DIRS=['/usr/local/include/coin']
    IPOPT_LIBS=['ipopt', 'coinhsl', 'coinlapack', 'coinblas', 'coinmumps', 'coinmetis']
    IPOPT_LIB_DIRS=['/usr/local/lib/']
    IPOPT_DLL=None
```

I modified the first and third line to point to the correct directory.

Now, the `lib` directory path (in the third line above) contains a library file named **libipopt.so**, **libipopt.so.0**, **libipopt.la** (same name, different extensions).

The setup is now not complaining about `IpStdCInterface.h` but it is unable to find the libs

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cyipopt.o -L/usr/local/lib/ -lipopt -lcoinhsl -lcoinlapack -lcoinblas -lcoinmumps -lcoinmetis -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/ipopt/cyipopt.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcoinhsl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcoinlapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcoinblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcoinmumps
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcoinmetis
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Those libs should be provided by the libipopt.so file? Or do I need to install some other package?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i have a same problem as you. My solution was add the following commands in .bashrc:

```
export IPOPT_HOME="/opt/CoinIpopt"

export PATH="${PATH}:${IPOPT_HOME}/bin"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${IPOPT_HOME}/lib"
```

/opt/CoinIpopt is the path which the IpOpt was installed.